# Why is a BGR image displayed as grayscale?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

## Context

I'm using Google Colab with OpenCV to work on a `.jpg` image. Colab has issues with OpenCV's `imshow` function, so `matplotlib` is used for the printing of images. I know that OpenCV uses BGR and to display things properly with `matplotlib` I need to use `cv2`'s `cvtColor()` function.

## Issue

When loading an image and displaying it, it displays as grayscale even though by default it should be BGR. Similarly, after converting to grayscale and displaying the image, it shows up as BGR.

Since the images are stored as `numpy` arrays I tried finding the dimensions of these arrays. The image that should have been BGR (displayed as grayscale) was a three dimensional array as expected. Similarly, the image after conversion to grayscale was a two dimensional array, as expected, but it still displayed as BGR.

BGR image displaying as grayscale:

[image: BGR image displaying as grayscale]

Grayscale image displaying as BGR:

[image: Grayscale image displaying as BGR]

Comment: Try setting the colormap (`cmap`) on your `plt` to `gray`

Comment: for the second image use `plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Changing the colormap does fix the display issue, but any idea why this is happening in the first place? Seems like this is a hack to get things looking the way they should without actually fixing the underlying issue.

Comment: You also might want to read about colormaps here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

Comment: @populationzero No everything is perfectly fine. Matplotlib by default uses the 'viridis' colormap, letting your image appear the way it does. It has certain advantages (read the link above). 

If you use an image processing library such as Pillow
`from PIL import Image;
img = Image.fromarray(img);
img.save("test.png")`
your image will apear as a grayscale image. Matplotlib is not primarely intended for image processing.

Comment: @Rumo Why does the first image display as grayscale instead of BGR though? I understand the advantages of adding a color map to a grayscale image, but why make a BGR image gray? Edit: HansHirse is right the image is displaying in RBG/BGR in the first picture

Comment: If anyone wants to post this as an answer I can mark the problem as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption, that the original image `img` is displayed as grayscale in the first picture is wrong from my point of view, because:

- You already found out, that `img` has three color channels.
- It's kind of unlikely, that Matplotlib automatically converts an input image to grayscale.
- It seems, that there's a slight red-ish "glimmer" on the left side of the image. Side notice: Due to the different color ordering of OpenCV and Matplotlib, I suspect this "glimmer" actually to be blue-ish, which is even more likely in such photographs.

So, for the first picture: Your visual percerption was just fooled by the image itself. :-)

The actual grayscale converted image (your second picture) is shown with the standard colormap of Matplotlib. As Mark and others correctly pointed out, you should change your code as follows to get an actual "grayscale image":

```py
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In the case you want a color image transformed and displayed in grayscale:

```py
import matplotlib as plt

# Reading color image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread(path, 0)

plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

where path is file location.

Another method is to the conversion by yourself. The filter you then should use is as follows:

```py
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.3, 0.59, 0.11]) # colorspace order [R, G, B]

grey_img = rgb2gray(img)
```

Where R is red, G is green and B is blue.

Comment: I think you still need `plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')` else you get the default (viridis) colormap.